# Why were my edits repeatedly rejected? (N.B OP came by and made edits for me)

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, editing-help

I tried to make these edits:

[First edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7013066)

> Comment: Added 'not' in so this works for newly created objects only. I removed it in my Q for testing.

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7015498)

> Comment: The unedited answer does not work. The original intention is to provide working code that matches my code. I have edited my code, and I am reflecting this change in this answer.

Each time it was rejected:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. **Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner**

Emphasis mine

The original poster (OP) came by and made those edits [for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437208/autopopulate-a-set-of-generic-many-to-many-fields-in-django/28438196?noredirect=1#comment45239378_28438196).

> I've updated the answer with the edit you wanted to make, also added [0] to deal with the tuple issue

In my opinion, this comes under:

> To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages

From [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/1075247)

If that hadn't been done, then anyone coming by might have seen that my `not` in the question had been removed.

I understand and respect that you don't want edits that deviate from the original intent. I tried to be super-clear with my second edit reason.

How could I avoid this in the future? Change my edit reason to be *even clearer*?

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, you should've just left a comment on the answer and let the OP decide whether or not they wanted to incorporate the change. After your first edit was rejected, it is not wise to try to make the exact same edit again. The edit summary makes no sense without context, but even then, it was likely to be rejected for the same reason.

The issue with code changes is that not only is there a chance that the reviewers are unfamiliar with the language or the domain of the problem, but something like adding `not` to a conditional may completely change the answer. If the answer is wrong, the correct thing to do is to leave a downvote and comment, not to edit it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I knew what I was doing, and I guess when I no longer need to 'suggest' edits I'd probably do it again (on my own questions). In the future though I'll leave a comment.

Comment: @Pureferret: On your own questions you have far more leeway, and will always edit directly, as well as have a binding vote on edit-suggestions.